# Push bottomsheet up the keyboard

Tags: react-native

i'd love to have a bottomsheet pushed up the keyboard when I type so that I can see what I am typing, currently the results that I have are on the attached gif. How can I achieve what I need? I tried keyboardavoidingview and react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view but they are no working.

Link: https://imgflip.com/gif/6wtsah

Answer (score 0):

Some bottom sheets package not optimized for keyboard awareness . You should try this bottom sheet library https://jeremybarbet.github.io/react-native-modalize/#/ as it designed to solve that issue.

Comment: I will try this one thanks, but it is working fine on android phone, the problem is only on iPhone